# I add a class to my text input, but it does not render

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net-mvc

I am using autocomplete to populate a text field.
Where a user enters some text but does not select from autocomplete, I want to highlight that text field.

So in the jquery below;

```
var createAutocomplete = function () {
    var $input = $(this);

    var options = {
        source: $input.attr("data-scd-autocomplete"),
        select: updateAutocompleteForm,
        close: errorAutocompleteForm
    };

    $input.autocomplete(options);
};
```

Where the user fails to select from the list, the close event fires which calls this function;

```
   var errorAutocompleteForm = function(event, ui) {
        var $input = $(this);
        $input.removeAttr('class');
        $input.attr('class', '');
        $input.addClass("input-validation-error");
    };
```

So I remove the existing classes from the text field and insert the "input-validation-error" class. However the CSS in this class does not show up, and in IE Developer Tools it shows that the CSS in this class is overridden. How do I stop this CSS from being overridden?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem
In my CSS I needed to connect the CSS class with the element type

```
input[type="text"].input-validation-error,
input[type="search"].input-validation-error,
input[type="password"].input-validation-error {
    border: solid 1px #e80c4d;
}
```

So previously `input[type="search"].input-validation-error` was missing. And the class

```
.input-validation-error
{
    border: 1px solid #ff0000;
    background-color: #ffeeee;
}
```

Was ignored. I have to admit I do not understand why this answer is the solution. So up ticks are available for those who can explain this.